# Update object in list based on object id

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I would like to know if it's possible to directly update an object in List by its id.
Here is my object structure :

```
public class MyObject {
    public UUID uuid;
    public String string1;
    public int int1;
    ...
}
```

In another Object I've an List of MyObject and I would like to update one of them by object id.
Is there any other solution besides the following code ?

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
// Add many object into my list
MyObject newObject = new MyObject(...);

list.removeIf(o -> o.getUuid().equals(newObject.getUuid()));
list.add(newObject);
```

Comment: Do you have to remove the object and replace it entirely ? Is it what you want ?
Or do you want to just update one the fields of the object ?
I mean if you have a way to get the index of the object you want to update, or directly the object, why not update the fields in the object directly ? (unless they're final or anything else)

Comment: If you want to have other alternate method, the answer is many way to do it. You can find by index for example.

Comment: Yes I would like to replace entire object

Comment: Alright, then tbh, I don't see anything much better if you want to REPLACE the whole item....
Unless you're willing to switch to another datastructure :
 then maybe you could use a HashMap, since you're using a unique id already as a key, you could go for : HashMap<UUID, MyObject>
And use either put() or replace(), depending on what you want exactly
EDIT: I can make an answer, if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compact, but hacky...

```
List<MyObject> list2 =
list.stream().map(item->item.getUuid().equals(newObject.getUuid()) ? newObject : item)
.collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the list and manually check the UUID each time if you really want to stick with using a `List`.

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(), i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getUuid().equals(newObject.getUuid())) {
        list.set(i, newObject());
        // Probably want to stop the loop here.
    }
}
```

Using `UUID` as a key for a `Map` makes it much simpler.

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<UUID, MyObject> map = list.stream().collect(Collecotrs.toMap(o -> o.getUuid(), o -> o));
map.put(newObject.getUuid(), newObject);
list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: Only thing to check here is wether a put(), or replace() is needed, since put() would add the object if it doesn't exist, but that's for the OP to decide.
Nice answer, better written than my comment !

Answer (score 0):

I think  that the easiest way is to implement hashcode/equals in such a way that it will target the UUID. Objects that match the UUID will be added and removed from the list when add() and remove() are called.

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Implementation using a LinkedList.");
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "A", 0));
        list.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "B", 1));
        list.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "C", 2));
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Remove an entry.");
        list.remove(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003")));
        System.out.println(list);
        list.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "D", 3));
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Adding a duplicate (creates a new entry).");
        list.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "A", 0));
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Remove duplicate (removes the first entry but not the last).");
        list.remove(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "A", 0));
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static class MyObject {
        public UUID uuid;
        public String string1;
        public int int1;

        public MyObject(UUID uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        public MyObject(UUID uuid, String string1, int int1) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            this.string1 = string1;
            this.int1 = int1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
            return Objects.equals(uuid, myObject.uuid);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(uuid);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObject{" +
                "uuid=" + uuid +
                ", string1='" + string1 + '\'' +
                ", int1=" + int1 +
                '}';
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Implementation using a LinkedList.
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='C', int1=2}]
Remove an entry.
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}]
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='D', int1=3}]
Adding a duplicate (creates a new entry).
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='D', int1=3}, MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}]
Remove duplicate (removes the first entry but not the last).
[MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='D', int1=3}, MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}]
```

The main issue here is that duplicates can be created (because we use a list)

If you need a way of preserving the order and exclude duplicates, use a LinkedHashSet

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Implementation using a LinkedHashSet");
        Set<MyObject> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        set.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "A", 0));
        set.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "B", 1));
        set.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "C", 2));
        System.out.println(set);
        System.out.println("Remove an entry.");
        set.remove(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003")));
        System.out.println(set);
        set.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "D", 3));
        System.out.println(set);
        System.out.println("Adding a duplicate (does not create a new entry).");
        set.add(new MyObject(UUID.fromString("299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003"), "A", 0));
        System.out.println(set);
    }

    public static class MyObject {
        public UUID uuid;
        public String string1;
        public int int1;

        public MyObject(UUID uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        public MyObject(UUID uuid, String string1, int int1) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            this.string1 = string1;
            this.int1 = int1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
            return Objects.equals(uuid, myObject.uuid);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(uuid);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObject{" +
                "uuid=" + uuid +
                ", string1='" + string1 + '\'' +
                ", int1=" + int1 +
                '}';
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Implementation using a LinkedHashSet
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=368b0214-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='C', int1=2}]
Remove an entry.
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}]
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='D', int1=3}]
Adding a duplicate (does not create a new entry).
[MyObject{uuid=299971c6-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='A', int1=0}, MyObject{uuid=31e77904-31b8-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='B', int1=1}, MyObject{uuid=9b21edea-31b9-11ec-8d3d-0242ac130003, string1='D', int1=3}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this:

```
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    
    int id = 4; //the UUID of the Object you are searching for
    
    MyObject found = list.stream()
            .filter(MyObject -> (MyObject.getUUID()==id))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
    
    int i = list.indexOf(found);
    int newUUID = 3;
    list.get(i).setUUID(newUUID);
```